# Búsqueda de un string en un array

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de realizar una búsqueda de un string dentro de un array y que este me devuelva todos los resultados que contengan esa palabra.

```js
var array=["1 de espadas","2 de espadas", "3 de espadas"];

function paloDeTruco(carta){
  return array.indexOf(carta);
}

paloDeTruco("espadas");
```

Esto me devuelve un -1, yo quiero que me devuelva los resultados en string

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso del metodo [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) que crea un nuevo array con todos los elementos que cumplan la condición implementada por la función dada y tambien utilizar el metodo [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/includes) que determina si una cadena de texto puede ser encontrada dentro de otra cadena de texto, retornando true o false según corresponda.

Por lo tanto tu código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```js
var array=["1 de espadas","2 de espadas", "3 de espadas"];

function paloDeTruco(carta){
  return array.filter(element => {
     return element.includes(carta);
  });
}

console.log(paloDeTruco("espadas"));
```

Comment: Esta es la solución ideal en mi opinión, respondí casi lo mismo pero no la había visto.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que pasa es que no estás buscando un valor exacto dentro del `array`, estás buscando un pedazo de texto contenido dentro de un valor, entonces para lograr esto debes iterar (recorrer) el `array` y comparar con cada valor si encuentra la coincidencia indicada:

```js
var array=["1 de espadas","2 de espadas", "3 de espadas"];

var resultado = '';

function paloDeTruco(carta){
  array.forEach(function(valor){
    if(valor.indexOf(carta) > -1){
      resultado += valor + ', ';
    }
  });
  
  console.log(resultado.slice(0, -2)); //Con slice quitamos la coma al final de la cadena de texto.
}

paloDeTruco("espadas");
```

Comment: No estas incluyendo la carta que se pasa por parámetro

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob a que te refieres? el parámetro de la función está!

Comment: Estas barriendo el arreglo y estas preguntando si el index en el que va existe en el arreglo, en ninguna parte preguntas por la carta que pasa como parámetro

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob pero de que hablas ? si sabes que el primer parámetro de forEach es el currentValue ?

Comment: Lo que digas, yo opino que está mal tu resultado

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob ya vi mi error, claro problema en la edición, pero tu debes saber que a forEach no es necesario pasarle el parámetro del index, su primer parámetro es el currentValue

Answer (score 1):

Creo que seria mejor retornar un array con los resultados asi:

```js
var array=["1 de espadas","2 de espadas", "2 de corazones", "3 de espadas"];

function paloDeTruco(carta){
  var resultados = [];
  array.forEach(function(card) {
    if(card.indexOf(carta) > -1) {
      resultados.push(card);
    }
  });
  return resultados;
}

console.log(paloDeTruco("espadas"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que barrer el arreglo, para comparar si existe en alguno de los resultados. Te dejo un ejemplo funcional

```js
const array = ["1 de espadas","2 de espadas", "3 de espadas"];

function paloDeTruco(carta){
  
  let result = [];
  array.forEach( ( index, i ) => {
   if( array[ i ].includes( carta ) ) {
     result.push( index );
   }
  });
  return result;
}

let carta = paloDeTruco("espadas");
console.log( carta );
```